# How do I merge and delete duplicated rows in SQL using UPDATE?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, greatest-n-per-group, sql-delete

For example, I have a table of:

```
id | code | name | type | deviceType
---+------+------+------+-----------
1  | 23   | xyz  | 0    | web
2  | 23   | xyz  | 0    | mobile
3  | 24   | xyzc | 0    | web
4  | 25   | xyzc | 0    | web
```

I want the result to be:

```
id | code | name | type | deviceType
---+------+------+------+-----------
1  | 23   | xyz  | 0    | web&mobile
2  | 24   | xyzc | 0    | web
3  | 25   | xyzc | 0    | web
```

How do I do this in SQL Server using `UPDATE` and `DELETE` statements?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are the ID columns unique? And Are you sure you want the device type to be concatenated instead of records per? Thats normally a bad practice, so I figured i would ask before doing anything.

Comment: And you also want to "renumber" the ID values of all the other unaffected rows? You need to rethink your table design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do what you want, you would need two separate statements.

This updates the "first" row of each group with all the device types in the group:

```
update t
set t.devicetype = t1.devicetype
from mytable t
inner join (
    select min(id) as id, string_agg(devicetype, '&') within group(order by id) as devicetype
    from mytable
    group by code, name, type
    having count(*) > 1
) t1 on t1.id = t.id
```

This deletes everything but the first row per group:

```
with t as (
    select row_number() over(partition by code, name, type order by id) rn
    from mytable
) 
delete from t where rn > 1
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=bb3ff7c0a541047b5b432f1e7f43f5ab)**

Comment: ...and both the delete and update would have to be wrapped in a single transaction, especially if this code were to be executed from an external calling application.

Comment: The answer by @TimBiegeleisen worked as well as this answer, I'm following this answer because this is exactly what I asked for and I'm sorta just testing some of the experiment on my own, thank you guys so much. +1

Answer (score 1):

I might actually suggest just leaving the original data intact, and instead creating a view here:

```sql
CREATE VIEW yourView AS
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY MIN(id)) AS id,
       code, name, type,
       STRING_AGG(deviceType, '&') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY id) AS deviceType
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY code, name, type;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

One main reason for *not* actually doing the update is that every time new data comes in, you might possibly have to run that update, over and over.  Instead, just keeping the original data and running the view occasionally might perform better here.

Note that I assume that you are using SQL Server 2017 or later.  If not, then `STRING_AGG` would have to be replaced with an uglier approach, but you should consider upgrading in this case.

Comment: `GROUP_CONCAT` isn't a T-SQL Function.

Comment: Id is different for common records.

Comment: Even though i was going to answer this suggesting something different, i think this is a much better approach. I was waiting on OP's reply as the intent might be whats required. But realistically this would be the best approach IMO.

Comment: Thank you for your solution, and your explanations, it truly helps me open my way of thinking. I will take note of it! +1